# How to get the return type of calling a functor with another type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Given types `TArgument` and `TFunctor`, how can I find out the resulting type of calling an instance of `TFunctor` with an argument of type `TArgument`?

This is my clumsy, dirty solution:

```
template <class TFunctor, typename TArgument>
class ReturnValue
{
public:
     typedef decltype(functor_(arguent_)) Type;

private:
     static TFunctor functor_;
     static TArgument arguent_;
}
```

but for it to work, both `TFunctor` and `TArgument` need to be default constructible.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef decltype(std::declval<TFunctor>()(std::declval<TArgument>())) Type;
```

Or using `std::result_of`:

```
typedef typename std::result_of<TFunctor(TArgument)>::type Type;
```